# Mint 17.3 Not Playing Sound

Tags: linux-mint, audio

My Toshiba Satellite A105 is running Linux Mint 17.3. It will not play any sound through the onboard hardware, and when I look into the sound menu, it only displays a dummy output. I have tried all the other solutions I found and spent nigh on 5 hours scouring Google, but nothing has worked thus far. Here is the output of `lspci`.

```
lspci | grep Audio

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
```

lsmod:

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_si3054    16384  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    69632  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    65536  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          32768  3 
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
dm_multipath           24576  0 
rfcomm                 61440  0 
bnep                   20480  2 
bluetooth             430080  10 bnep,rfcomm
scsi_dh                16384  1 dm_multipath
snd_hda_codec         122880  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
pcmcia                 53248  0 
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
coretemp               16384  0 
joydev                 20480  0 
serio_raw              16384  0 
snd_pcm                94208  6 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
binfmt_misc            20480  1 
toshiba_haps           16384  0 
toshiba_bluetooth      16384  0 
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
irda                  172032  0 
8250_fintek            16384  0 
tpm_infineon           20480  0 
yenta_socket           40960  0 
crc_ccitt              16384  1 irda
arc4                   16384  2 
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_seq_midi
tifm_7xx1              16384  0 
tifm_core              16384  1 tifm_7xx1
iwl3945                65536  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            20480  1 yenta_socket
lpc_ich                20480  0 
iwlegacy               90112  1 iwl3945
snd_seq                57344  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
pcmcia_core            24576  3 pcmcia,pcmcia_rsrc,yenta_socket
mac80211              618496  2 iwl3945,iwlegacy
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              450560  3 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211
snd_timer              28672  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69632  15 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
shpchp                 32768  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     16384  0 
parport                40960  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
dm_mirror              24576  0 
dm_region_hash         20480  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 49152  0 
hid                    98304  2 hid_generic,usbhid
i915                  921600  3 
firewire_ohci          36864  0 
psmouse               102400  0 
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
sdhci_pci              20480  0 
drm_kms_helper        114688  1 i915
pata_acpi              16384  0 
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
e100                   36864  0 
mii                    16384  1 e100
drm                   286720  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
video                  20480  1 i915
```

[image: AlsaMixer]
[image: Updated Alsamixer]

after opening and resetting alsamixer, I unmuted everything in the all selection, selected the current sound card, and tested the sound. After finding that the sound was working again, I exited alsamixer and rebooted, and retested the sound, and it was no longer working. I've tried

```
sudo alsactl store
```

but got

```
alsactl: get_control:256: Cannot read control '3,6,0,Playback Channel Map,0' : Invalid argument
```

every time I run it.

```
ps aux | grep pulse
```

results in:

```
hunter    1761  0.0  0.6  89324  6996 ?      S<l  14:05  0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog


ls -lah /run/user/1000/pulse/
```

results in:

```
ls -lah /run/user/1000/pulse/
total 4.0K
drwx------ 2 hunter hunter  80 Apr 17 14:05 .
drwx------ 6 hunter hunter 140 Apr 17 14:05 ..
srwxrwxrwx 1 hunter hunter   0 Apr 17 14:05 native
-rw------- 1 hunter hunter   5 Apr 17 14:05 pid
```

I finally got fed up because Alsamixer wouldn't save, so I use Nano to open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state, which is the default save file, unmuted everything, set everything to the max volume, then saved and quit. To get rid of the dummy output, I created an executable .txt file that, when run, forces alsa to restart, and that brings back the sound.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38517/discussion-on-question-by-hunter-peters-mint-17-3-not-playing-sound).

Comment: @terdon Unfortunately, the poster doesn't have enough rep for chat.

Comment: @FaheemMitha if you use the "move to chat" link that appears when you post too many comments, the people participating in the comment thread are automatically given read/write access to the created chat room, irrespective of rep. The OP has access to the room I created for your thread.

Comment: @terdon Oh, I didn't know that. Noted for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: "To get rid of the dummy output, I created an executable .txt file that, when run, forces alsa to restart, and that brings back the sound." Details? What are the contents of your executable `txt` file?

Comment: @FaheemMitha It's an sh file; command it runs is sudo alsa force-restart, got the idea from looking on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posters sound card was muted.

He ran `alsamixer`, unmuted the mixer controls, and raised the levels. This got the card working.

However, the card returned to muted on rebooting. The Alsa config should be saved and restored on rebooting. So this is an outstanding issue.

NOTE: poster says he has no `~/.pulse`. This should definitely be present. I enclose mine below for reference.

```
faheem@orwell:~/.pulse$ ls -laR
.:
total 216
drwx------   2 faheem faheem   4096 May  7  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x 449 faheem faheem 126976 Apr 17 23:15 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 faheem faheem  12288 Mar  2 20:10 501a8b6f724c87677a6f6bb351f93f66-card-database.tdb
-rw-r--r--   1 faheem faheem     43 Mar 12 06:43 501a8b6f724c87677a6f6bb351f93f66-default-sink
-rw-r--r--   1 faheem faheem     42 Mar 12 06:43 501a8b6f724c87677a6f6bb351f93f66-default-source
-rw-r--r--   1 faheem faheem  24576 Mar  2 20:10 501a8b6f724c87677a6f6bb351f93f66-device-manager.tdb
-rw-r--r--   1 faheem faheem  28672 Mar  2 20:10 501a8b6f724c87677a6f6bb351f93f66-device-volumes.tdb
lrwxrwxrwx   1 faheem faheem     23 May  7  2015 501a8b6f724c87677a6f6bb351f93f66-runtime -> /tmp/pulse-89U0MVRj2HDL
-rw-r--r--   1 faheem faheem  12288 Apr  5 01:54 501a8b6f724c87677a6f6bb351f93f66-stream-volumes.tdb
lrwxrwxrwx   1 faheem faheem     23 Jul 30  2013 625c93e846d53a6969a9cd0045cef420-runtime -> /tmp/pulse-SitwwRMh3jor
```

Comment: I got Alsamixer to save, ran nano as root and edited the file, now I just need to get it off Dummy.

Comment: Hi @HunterPeters. Tell us how you got `alsamixer` to save. And edited what file?

Comment: Well, Alsamixer wouldn't save, so I use Nano to open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state, which is the default save file, unmuted everything, set everything to the max volume, then saved and quit. I'll also put this in the question.

Comment: I'm surprised that worked. Did someone suggest this?

Comment: Nope, I tested it on one thing first and it worked so I did it for the rest.

Comment: That feels like a bit of a hacky workaround, but I guess if it works, it works. But your mixer settings really should be saved automatically. I'm guessing the problem is with your pulseaudio setup.